# Fitting a line via lm

Tags: r

My code doesn't work. I am trying to find the relationship between 4 set of data briefly by lm function.

My data is as follow

```
X1,Y1, X2, Y2,X3,Y3
1,2,3,4,5,6
6,5,4,3,2,1
2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2
```

The easiest way is simply

```
fit=lm(X1,Y1)
summary(fit)
```

instead of typing fit1, fit2, fit3, i would like to do all at once.

I have also tried `get_regression_table(fit[n], print=TRUE)`but it still doesn't work

`fit[n]<-lm(Yn~Xn,data=mydata)
for (n in 1:3){
  get_regression_table(fit[n], print=TRUE)
}`

Comment: @G5W indeed. but even if i change it to 4, it still doesn't work properly. I receive different errors - mainly is Y is not defined yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically call the `lm` function using `do.call`. And passing the parameters as strings.

```
data = data.frame(X1 = c(1,6,2,7),Y1 = c(2,5,3,5),X2 = c(3,4,4,5),Y2 = c(4,3,5,4),X3 = c(5,2,6,3),Y3 = c(6,1,7,2))

results = vector("list",3)
for(i in seq(1,3)){
  formula = paste0("Y",i,"~","X",i)
  results[[i]] = do.call("lm",list(formula = formula,data = quote(data)))
}
```

Each element in results contains the `i`th fit.

Comment: You dont actually need `do.call` for this. `lm(formula, data)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a matrix for storing your values and then use a variable to loop over your needed indexes

```
mat <- t(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,2),6,4))
matfit <- list()
length(fit) <- 3
for(i in 1:3){
  fit[[i]] <- lm(mat[,i*2-1] ~ mat[,i*2])
}
```